# PHP: How to know which class called the logic inside a Trait?

Tags: php, php-7.2

In Laravel I have several Artisan commands that do different things but share some piece of logic. To not repeat myself I moved that logic to a trait (mainly the `handle()` method. Everything works smoothly however…

If I have `FooCommand` and `BarCommand` and both commands `use BazTrait` then inside the `BazTrait`:

```
trait BazTrait
{
    public function handle()
    {
        // how to get the name of the class (FooCommand or BarCommand)
        // that called this code right now?

        dd(classThatCalledThis) // expect to dump either FooCommand or BarCommand
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks for any hints.

> vagrant@homestead:~/Code/foo$ php -v PHP
>   7.2.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 07:16:54) ( NTS )

Comment: WIth `__CLASS__`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [magic constants page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> Note that as of PHP 5.4 `__CLASS__` works also in traits. When used in a trait method, `__CLASS__` is the name of the class the trait is used in.

you can use `__CLASS__`:

```
dd(__CLASS__);
```

**But** the most reliable way (in case of inheritance and all this stuff) is:

```
dd(static::class);
```

A fiddle is [here](https://3v4l.org/PTqnX), it shows you difference between `__CLASS__` and `static::class`.

Comment: Ohh crap guys! I'm too tired today apparently. Thanks!  

Comment: I will accept this one for extra info. Thanks again.

Comment: Added more reliable way with `static::class`.

Answer (score 0):

get_class returns the name of the class of the passed object. Since you are in one of the object's method, inherited from the trait you can use this to access the current object.

```
$classThatCalledThis = get_class($this);
```

See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-class.php